# parse ObjectsDidLoad called twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I have a PFQueryTableViewController which contain a segmentedControl which switch to a MKMapView. When this is clicked i want to load the geoPoint objects from objectsDidLoad, but since the objectsDidLoad is called twice it will duplicate the annonationPoints on the map. Why is it being called twice?

```
override func objectsDidLoad(error: NSError!) {
    super.objectsDidLoad(error)
    if error == nil {
        println("lol")
    }
}
```

cache

```
    if self.objects.count == 0 {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }
```

Comment: What cache behaviour have you specified?  If you have caching enabled then the method will be called once when the objects are retrieved from cache and then again when the data is loaded from the web backend.  You should simply remove all annotations in `objectsDidLoad`

Comment: So i would need to remove the cachePolicy ?

Comment: Either that or remove the existing annotations at the start of objectsDidLoad

Answer (score 3):

`kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork` will result in two calls to `objectsDidLoad` - The first when the objects are retrieved from cache and then again when the objects are retrieved from the network.

You should remove all existing map annotations at the start of this method - Remember to perform this on the main thread.

See also - https://www.parse.com/questions/determine-if-query-result-or-object-originates-from-cache